# Sending email day before assigned task

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a module that is related to give me a message before the day when anyone assigned me the task/project. Like anyone assigns me task at `7-10-2019` and add my email from the system so I will get an email. But at the date of `6-10-2019` I will get a reminder (email will come to my account that tomorrow 7-10-2019) there will be a task for me. I am working with `CakePHP`, I did the code and also set cronjob into my `Cpanel` but I didn't get any email. Here is my code and also attached the **`cronjob`** configuration image.

```
public function sendRequestBeforeReliverDay()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $nowTime = date('Y-m-d');

    $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", time() + 86400);

    $reliverFind = $this->EmpLeaves->find('all')->WHERE(['date_from' => $tomorrow])->contain(['Employees'])->toArray();

    $relieversEmail = $reliverFinds->employee->office_email;

    if($reliverFind)
    {
        $emailTo = array();
        $emailTo[] = 'samuel.rodrigues@sjinnovation.com';
        $emailTo[] = 'anik.roy@sjinnovation.com';
        //$emailTo[] = $relieversEmail;

        $email = new Email();
        $email->setfrom(['connect@sjinnovation.com' => 'SJ Connect'])
            ->setto($emailTo)
            ->setemailFormat('html')
            ->setTemplate('send_email_to_reliever_the_day_before')
            ->setsubject($applierName . ' Application for reliver notification #' . rand(108512, 709651))
            ->setViewVars(['applierName' => $applierName,
            'first_name' => $empName,
            'dateFrom' => $dateFrom,
            'dateTo' => $dateTo,
            'no_of_days' => $no_of_days,
            'leaveType' => $leaveType])
            ->send();
    } 
}
```

**`cronjob`** configuration attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEP5g.png)

Comment: cron never runs at 12am remember this. you can push 1 min ahead.

Comment: Thank you , i changed this @AmolBhandariSJ